# Llamar un form en proyecto VB de solucion de C#

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tardes, estoy trabajando con VS2017, tengo una solucion que consta de varias proyectos, los primeros que hice los trabaje en VB, los nuevo los tengo ahora en C# me estoy pasando a esta ultima.

Mi problema es que el MDI principal esta en VB, hago el import DXAfacturacion que esta en C# y no veo los formularios o reportes, ya hice la referencia en las propiedaes, me podrian indicar que debo referenciar mas.

saludos

Comment: Con los datos que nos das, es dificil saber que te está pasando. En principio el proceso es primero añadir una referencia en el proyecto principal al secundario, y despues añadir un `Imports`  dentro del código donde quieres llamar al formulario en C#.

Comment: Ya agregue las referencias en la partes de referencias, luego cuando hago el import en el MDI o form principal del menu del sistema no ve esta referencia, segundo que hago hay una opcion que dice import/namespace, tampoco me los toma encuenta.